# Sitecore xConnect generating a JSON file for my custom model

Tags: xconnect

Hello i have been trying out the new xConnect in Sitecore 9.
I am now trying to add custom facets to xConnect.
To deploy these i need to create a json representation of my model.

I have created a class library with my facets and CollectionModel.

```
public class CollectionModel
{
    public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildModel();

    private static XdbModel BuildModel()
    {
        XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("DemoModel", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
        modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, CartInfo>(CartInfo.DefaultFacetKey);
        modelBuilder.DefineFacet<Interaction, StoreInfo>(StoreInfo.DefaultFacetKey);

        return modelBuilder.BuildModel();
    }
}

[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
class CartInfo : Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "CartInfo";
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
class Product : Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "Product";
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
class StoreInfo : Facet
{
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "StoreInfo";
    public Guid StoreID { get; set; }
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> ActiveOffers { get; set; }
}
```

Now i am trying to convert this to json and export it to a file in a console application like so:

```
var model = Sitecore.XConnect.Serialization.XdbModelWriter.Serialize(CollectionModel.Model);
File.WriteAllText(CollectionModel.Model.FullName + ".json" , model);
```

When i run this i get the following error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Interactive.Async, Version=3.0.3000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263’ or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does anyone know what i am missing?

Comment: System.Interactive.Async is xConnect dependendcy which should be installed when Sitecore is deployed. A quick fix is to install the package from nuget:

    **Install-Package System.Interactive.Async**

To find the reason why the dependency is missing you could check Sitecore's installation log file if any errors occurred during installation.

Comment: I believe i might have a wrong version of something somewhere, after installing the package i still get the error

Comment: @SitecoreClimber how do you mean, i have not realy touched sitecore itself yet. I have added the same Sitecore.XConnect.dll to my console application and class library

Comment: @grg i have checked the logs and it has added the System.Interactive.Async without errors

Comment: can you reference model in this way :  XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("DemoModel", new XdbModelVersion(0, 1));
            modelBuilder.ReferenceModel(CollectionModel.Model);

Comment: @SitecoreClimber it crashes on the "XdbModelBuilder modelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("DemoModel", new XdbModelVersion(0, 1));" line so that would make a difference i believe.

Comment: I am now adding a bunch of references to my console application, it seems like i created the console application in the wrong place (should be in the xConnect folder or something?)

Comment: After adding a bunch of references i was able to create the json model, i'll try to find out what i did wrong and update my post

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After playing around a little i found out that you have to add some references to your Console application. These can all be found in the bin folder of your xConnect or Sitecore project:

- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
- Sitecore.XConnect.dll
- Sitecore.XConnect.Search.dll
- System.Interactive.Async.dll
- System.Interactive.Async.Providers.dll

This guide describes the creation and deployment of custom xConnect models very well:
https://citizensitecore.com/2017/10/17/xconnect-adding-custom-facets-in-sitecore-9/comment-page-1/#comment-323

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong Mark. Because you're creating a connection to xConnect outside of a Sitecore context there are some dependencies that are necessary that aren't present. I point those dependencies out [in this post](https://citizensitecore.com/2017/10/17/xconnect-creating-contacts-in-sitecore-9/) when initializing the `XConnectClient`. Keep in mind, those posts were written using the Technical Preview of SC9 - I need to update them to reflect changes to the Initial Release because you don't have to call `File.WriteAllText(CollectionModel.Model.FullName + ".json" , model);` anymore.

Comment: Oh, and thank you for referencing my post - glad it was helpful! :)